# Even though I have created two seperate lists, why is the if condition true

Tags: python, list, if-statement, boolean

```
even = [10, 4, 6, 8]
another_even = list(even)
print(another_even is even)
if another_even == even:
    another_even.sort( reverse=True )
    print(even)
else:
    print("Yay")
```

Output:
False

[10, 4, 6, 8]

Even though I have created two seperate list then why the if condition is true.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a difference between \`==\` and \`is\` in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python)

Comment: The if condition is True because the two objects are equal but they are not the same object. They are two diffferent containers with the same numbers inside. list(data) creates a new list from the data in data. data can be any iterable. In this case there is the coincidence of data being also a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
even = [10, 4, 6, 8]
another_even = list(even)
```

`even` is one *list*
`another_even` is a different list which you constructed by using the elements in `even`.

Notice: **different**. They are two different objects.

That's why:

```
print(another_even is even)
```

prints `False`. It is because `even` and `another_even` are **not** the same object.

If you had done this:

```
another_even = even
```

you would have gotten `True`

But now you test for *equality* with:

```
if another_even == even:
    another_even.sort( reverse=True )
    print(even)
else:
    print("Yay")
```

And `==` will compare the elements inside `even` against the `elements` inside `another_even`. Because the length of the lists and the elements are equal, the comparison evaluates to `True` and this code executes:

```
    another_even.sort( reverse=True )
    print(even)
```

You could think of the `==` comparison as executing this other code:

```
result = True
for x, y in zip(even, another_even):
    if x != y:
        result = False
        break
```

The elements are compared one to one and in case one pair fails to be equal, the result will be False. In your case all elements are equal.

Note: you can check that the objects `even` and `another_even` are different doing this:

```
print(id(even))
print(id(another_even))
```

And the output will be different, hence the `False` from `even is another_even`